# Image transitions not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, transition

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnykg/

When you hover over the image its supposed to fade transition into the other image, but in firefox the transition is broken. I tried adding a top: 0px; which was suggested from a similar question asked, but still doesn't work.

```
.infidus {
    margin-left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width:698px;
    height:300px;
    background: url();
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

.infidus:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width:698px;
    height:300px;
    background: url();
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3c list of animatable properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animation-of-property-types-) background-image is not an animatable property. Although some browsers like chrome support this cross-fading behavior.

For firefox, [bug 546052](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052) is filed for this kind of transition.

However you can achieve what you want by doing some tricks that are described at the following links:

[CSS3 background image transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition)

[CSS3 Fade Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079330/css3-fade-effect)