# how do I fade background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote the following function to change the background image of the page to the current slide in the slider but the fade effect only works in chrome. What do I change to make the same effect happen in other browsers?

```
onAfterChange: function (center, index) {

    if (center.currentSlide === 0) {
        $('body').css('backgroundImage' ,  "url('image1.jpg')");
    } else if (center.currentSlide === 1) {
        $('body').css('backgroundImage' ,  "url('image2.jpg')");
    } else if (center.currentSlide === 2) {
        $('body').css('backgroundImage' ,  "url('image3.jpg')");
    } else if (center.currentSlide === 3) {
        $('body').css('backgroundImage' ,  "url('image4.jpg')");
    }
}
```

and the css I'm using looks like

```
-webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease;
-moz-transition: background-image 1s ease;
-ms-transition: background-image 1s ease;
-o-transition: background-image 1s ease;
transition: background-image 1s ease;
```

Comment: Try `transition: background-image 1s ease;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, they're still snapping instead of a nice smooth fade like I'm hoping for.

Comment: what's wrong with jquery effects like fadeOut?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Fade Effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079330/css3-fade-effect)

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using fadeOut, I'm just new to all this fancy stuff and this is what I currently have that works, not sure where to put a fadeOut and fadeIn in the function.

Comment: Tried getting it to work with the link provided but have not been able to yet.

Comment: Have you installed jquery easing?  http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: No, didn't know I needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the jQuery plugin anystretch. Works just like backstretch but also gives you an option to specify the fadeIn time.

My edited code:

```
if (center.currentSlide === 0) {
                $('body').anystretch("images/sign.png", {speed:1500});
            } else if (center.currentSlide === 1) {
                $('body').anystretch("images/temple.png", {speed:1500});
            } else if (center.currentSlide === 2) {
                $('body').anystretch("images/park.png", {speed:1500});
            } else if (center.currentSlide === 3) {
                $('body').anystretch("images/water.png", {speed:1500});
            }
```