# Change Background image with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i make my inline styled div to change it background image url after 5 second?

Example:

`<div class="foobar" style=" background(url'red.png'; "> </div>`

After 5 seconds, it need to be:

`<div class="foobar" style=" background(url'blue.png'; "> </div>`

and After 5 seconds, it need be:

`<div class="foobar" style=" background(url'yellow.png'; "> </div>`

So, It can cycle 3 images in this foobar, Red, Blue and Yellow background images.

Comment: will it repeat the images like a loop or show just once??

Comment: Some hint: You can use `setInterval` to achieve this. Call a function on load of the body tag. Eg:- ` <body onload="myFunction()">`

Comment: @Andrew I am working on fiddle but not even with class working with simple example.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Yes it will loop

Comment: See this links, maybe help you: [css3-fade-effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079330/css3-fade-effect) and [fade-in-a-background-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319552/can-i-fade-in-a-background-image-css-background-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this is what you are looking for?

I have 3 different fades for the background colour. Using CSS keyframes

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes colorbox {
  0% {
    background:red;
  }
  40% {
    background: green;
  }
  80% {
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}

.box {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   animation: colorbox 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

**See it working**

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/thy1z34v/)

If you need some more information about CSS Keyframe animations have a look a look at this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things:

1. Create a timeout that will run after specific delay and do some task
2. You will have to use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` for bounce effect.
3. You will have to reset class and add corresponding class. This needs to be done after `fadeOut` and before `fadeIn`.

#### Sample

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/waxLnh75/1/)

```js
var count = 1;
var class_list = ["red", "blue", "green"];
function animateDiv(){
 $("#content").fadeOut(400,updateClass);
}

function updateClass(){
 $("#content").removeClass("red blue green").addClass(class_list[count++ % class_list.length]).fadeIn(400);
}

function initInterval(){
 setInterval(animateDiv, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 initInterval();
})
```

```css
.red{
  background: red;
}
.blue{
  background:blue;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
div{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="red"></div>
```

**Note:** You will have to pass `fadeIn` code as a callback, so that it is executed after `fadeOut` is completed.

#### Reference

- [FadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)
- [FadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)