# Target CSS inline background with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

So i'm trying to manipulate my background by fading it out on mouseleave.

But i cannot target it with jquery.

jQuery:

```
$("html").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',0.67,function(){
            $("#intro").css("background"); //attempting to target bg

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#intro{
   background: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/intro.jpg");
}
```

how do i target this background?

Comment: You might find this helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079330/css3-fade-effect

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, however, this isn't what I'm looking to achieve. I'm just trying to target the background.

Comment: Your call to `css()` just gets the value of the background property. If you want to set it, pass on the second argument...

Comment: When i do $("#intro").css("background","url(images/intro.jpg)");
it just completely removes the background instead.
Would this work?   $("#intro").css("background").fadeTo('slow',0.67);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call **$('#intro').fadeTo** you are saying you want to animate the opacity of **intro**. The third argument of fadeTo is a function that is called once the animation is completed, you can't change the target of fadeTo with it. The opacity of an element always affect its descendants. You can't use fadeTo to achieve what you want.

As a work around, set the background image of **intro** with the **::after** pseudo-element. Initialize its opacity to 0.67 and change it to 1.0 on hover. See the details in this snippet:

```css
body{
    background: #000;
}
#intro{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px ;
    height: 300px ;
}
#intro::after{
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/550px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg);
    opacity: 0.67;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 600ms;
}
#intro:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;
}
#intro p{
    color: #fff;
}
#intro img{
    width: 100px ;
    height: auto ;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro">
    <p>La Gioconda</p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/550px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',0.67,function(){
            $("#intro").css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')'); //attempting to target bg

    });
});
```

Comment: This still targets all of the elements inside of the div.

Answer (score 0):

> Aprroach1:

```js
$("html").mouseleave(function(){
    
     $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',0.67,function(){
             $("#intro").removeClass().addClass("intro-back2"); //attempting to target bg             
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
   .intro-back1{
       background: url("http://www.bhagesh.com/images/portfolio-nature-small.jpg");
   }
   .intro-back2{
       background: url("http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/zwergmanguste_nager_rodent_227139.jpg");
   }  
   #intro{
    width:300px;
    height:300px; 
   }
</style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="intro" class="intro-back1">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

> You can change background when *mouseover* on #intro

Plus

> Approach2:

```js
$("html").mouseleave(function(){
    
     $('#intro').fadeTo('slow',0.67,function(){
             $("#intro").removeClass().addClass("intro-back2"); //attempting to target bg             
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
   #opac{
                opacity:0.67;
    width:300px;
                position:relative;
    height:300px;
   }
   .intro-back1{
       background: url("http://www.bhagesh.com/images/portfolio-nature-small.jpg");
   }
   .intro-back2{
       background: url("http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/zwergmanguste_nager_rodent_227139.jpg");
   }  
   #intro{                    
                position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px; 
   }
</style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="intro" class="intro-back1">
  </div>
  <div id="opac" class="intro-back1">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```